# Handle Thumb.DragCompleted immediately WPF on slow computer

Tags: c#, wpf, video

I have some software that does the following:

1. Shows a video image updating with 25Hz
2. Makes a video overlay
3. Uses a Thumb as a joystick control to move the camera.

This works perfectly on a fast computer but on a slow computer the video image update takes up so many resources that the thumb does not get updated and sometimes takes up to 5 seconds from the moment that I have let go of the thumb before the Thumb.DragCompleted is fired.

I have tried many different methods including using the `Monitor.TryEnter(LockVideo, 0)` function to make sure that the video image update is only updated if the last image has already finished but this doesn't seem to help.
What I would want is to be able to give the UI priority over the updating of the screen, but since they all work in the same thread this seems to be difficult.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: What are the images coming into the GUI thread as?  Bitmaps, or something more complex?

Comment: They are coming via InteropBitmap from a frame grabber.